# Spark Streaming app gets stuck with Amazon Keyspace

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, spark-structured-streaming, spark-cassandra-connector, amazon-keyspaces

We are using spark Cassandra Connector (com.datastax.spark:spark-cassandra-connector_2.12:3.2.0) to connect with Amazon Keyspace. Observed very strange issue where streaming application gets stuck after processing certain amount of data across multiple micro-batches. There is no definite way to reproduce issue and it could happen any time after certain duration.

Could see all Cassandra Connector threads are stuck around below lines.

```
sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.epollWait(Native Method)
sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.poll(EPollArrayWrapper.java:281)
sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl.doSelect(EPollSelectorImpl.java:105)
sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:98) => holding Monitor(com.datastax.oss.driver.shaded.netty.channel.nio.SelectedSelectionKeySet@-1275491359})
sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:109)
com.datastax.oss.driver.shaded.netty.channel.nio.SelectedSelectionKeySetSelector.select(SelectedSelectionKeySetSelector.java:62)
com.datastax.oss.driver.shaded.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.select(NioEventLoop.java:814)
com.datastax.oss.driver.shaded.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:457)
com.datastax.oss.driver.shaded.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
com.datastax.oss.driver.shaded.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
com.datastax.oss.driver.shaded.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830)
```

Can you have a look at the above logs and help us understand any possible reason for this.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the stack trace you posted is too generic and mostly concerned with network I/O which isn't very helpful.

You will need to do a bit more investigation to narrow it down. Try to identify a specific Spark application/job that is problematic then using the Spark UI, narrow down the code where you think it is getting stuck. Cheers!

Comment: On debugging it further, we could see Cassandra thread is stuck with schema refresh. Can you have an insight on possible scenarios when schema refresh happens and possibly when it can get stuck ? I see similar situation posted here (https://community.datastax.com/questions/8673/spark-streaming-gets-stucked-cassandra-connector-3.html) but no definite solution for that.

Stuck getting result from below line :-
`com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.session.Session.refreshSchema(Session.java:140)`

Comment: Unfortunately, this is only the second time I've heard of someone running into this issue. If you're able to provide steps + minimal code that reproduces it, we'd be happy to look into it. Cheers!

Comment: Query gets stuck when there is connection lost with Keyspaces. Below stack trace is printed in debug logs. However, this exception is not propagated till caller. If this exception is propagated till the caller level, then exception can be caught and some manual intervention for automatic restart can be ensured. However, it's not happening.

Stack trace posted in below comment :-

Comment: `[DEBUG] [SchemaAgreementChecker]: [s0] Error while checking schema agreement, completing now (false)
java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: com.datastax.oss.driver.shaded.netty.channel.StacklessClosedChannelException
 at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.adminrequest.AdminRequestHandler.setFinalError(AdminRequestHandler.java:204) ~[java-driver-core-shaded-4.13.0.jar:?]
 at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.adminrequest.AdminRequestHandler.onWriteComplete(AdminRequestHandler.java:148) ~[java-driver-core-shaded-4.13.0.jar:?]`

Comment: The exception gets thrown when the underlying Java driver used by the connector is requesting the schema from the cluster. You didn't post the full stack trace so I'm not completely sure of what is happening but my guess is that the check for schema agreement timed out. Is it possible you have hundreds of tables defined?

Comment: Yes, exception is happening while checking schema agreement. So basically on every call to Cassandra via Spark Cassandra Connector, schema agreement is checked. Over here, connection to cassandra cluster is getting dropped and exception is logged in debug logs. It just logs this exception in debug logs and stuck. Exception is not routed on to driver program.

Stack Trace :-

<code>

Comment: Added stack trace here (https://pastebin.com/TiVjzgGW). It is printed along with debug logs and not propagated to the caller.

Comment: Issue is reproducible when Control Connection channel goes down during schema refresh process. At that point, application gets stuck

Comment: On debugging it further found an issue with below code snippet within MetadataManager.java. Future reference over here is not completed anytime in case control connection goes down during schema refresh process and application is stuck. When control connection goes down, exception is thrown while initializing SchemaQueries instance using `schemaQueriesFactory.newInstance()`. This block of code is within whenComplete method and any exception thrown over here reference is lost and not propagated or handled. 

Source Code Details :-
https://pastebin.com/SKK6jDkq

Comment: @VarunArora Were you able to find the solution for this ?

Comment: @Knight71 There are issues in library related to usage of asynchronous programming. Exception handling is not proper. In order to handle that overridden newInstance method of  DefaultSchemaQueriesFactory.java class to handle exception.

https://pastebin.com/xK8195wT

Comment: Refer code here : https://pastebin.com/knPemctD